# declaring log4j.properties in a web deployed applet

Tags: java, jsp, logging, applet, log4j

I have an applet which is deployed using the applet tag in a jsp. I sign all the libraries to be used and add them to the classpath by including them in the "archive" property of the applet tag (including apache-log4jSigned.jar). But when i try to deploy the application in a tomcat server and run it, it does not create an error. I did some research and apparently log4j.property file should also be added to the classpath using (""archive" property) i tried the following. archive=".., /src/log4j.properties"this didnt work. Then i tried to zip the log.properties file change the extension to jar and include it in the applet's class path through eclipse's run configuration. even this didnt help. but when i run the applet in my local system, log files are created. How can i get this working in the web deployment. it would be great if you can provide an example.

Thanks.

Update: This is what i did to make it work.
1)i zipped my properties file
2)changed the extension to jar from zip
3)places it in the same folder as other jars added it to class path along with other jar libraries

but now the problem is.. it creates the log file in the user's system.. not in tomcat's folders.

Comment: Please enter that as an answer when the site allows and accept the answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did to make it work. 
1)i zipped my properties file 
2)changed the extension to jar from zip 
3)placed it in the same folder as other jars added it to class path (right click on project in Eclipse->properties->java buildpath->add jars) along with other jar libraries
this is where i got the solution from http://www.coderanch.com/t/106042/vc/Eclipse-add-log-properties-classpath

but now the problem is.. it creates the log file in the user's system.. not in tomcat's folders. I have been researching on google for  quite some time and i didnt find a complete discussion about this topic.